# Why is pytesseract causing AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bands'?

Tags: python-2.7, python-imaging-library, ocr

I am trying to get started using pytesseract but as you can see below I am having problems.

I have found people getting what seems to be the same error and they say that it is a bug in PIL 1.1.7. Others say the problem is caused by PIL being lazy and one needs to force PIL to load the image with `im.load()` after opening it, but that didn't seem to help. Any suggestions gratefully received.

```
K:\Glamdring\Projects\Images\OCR>python
Python 2.7.8 (default, Jun 30 2014, 16:03:49) [MSC v.1500 32 bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> from PIL import Image
>>> import pytesseract
>>> pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open('foo.png'))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "build\bdist.win32\egg\pytesseract\pytesseract.py", line 143, in image_to_string
  File "c:\Python27_32\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py", line 1497, in split
    if self.im.bands == 1:
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bands'
```

Comment: Could you post the image which is causing this problem?

Answer (score 4):

Try to use objects from Image and pytesseract module separately.

It solved my problem:

```
try:
    import Image
except ImportError:
    from PIL import Image
import pytesseract

img = Image.open('myImage.jpg')
img.load()
i = pytesseract.image_to_string(img)
print i
```

Answer (score 3):

***I have no prior experience*** with `PIL` but I was bored so I tried to look into it and, from what I can tell, it is ***probably*** a bug.

---

This isn't a fault of `pytesseract` if we look at the execution steps.

- Initially your `Image.open('foo.png')` works perfectly fine with no errors relating to your stack-trace.
- `pytesseract.image_to_string(img)` comes in afterwards and does the following:

  ```
  # Omitting the rest of the method.

  # calls method split() of your image object.
  if len(image.split()) == 4:
  ```

  This is the ***first*** statement acting on `image` so we know we have to look back into `PIL` to find the root of the problem.
- Your stacktrace has the specific message `AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'bands'` with regard to the `if self.im.bands` statement. This means that `im` is the `object = None`.

  Lets look into the `image.split()` method:

  ```
  """
  Split this image into individual bands. This method returns a
  tuple of individual image bands from an image. For example,
  splitting an "RGB" image creates three new images each
  containing a copy of one of the original bands (red, green,
  blue).

  :returns: A tuple containing bands.
  """

  self.load() # This is the culprit since..
  if self.im.bands == 1: # .. here the im attribute of the image = None
      ims = [self.copy()]

  # Omitting the rest ---
  ```

  Obviously `self.load()` sets, among others, the `im` value. I verified this with a test Image and it seemed to work with no issues [*I suggest you try the same with your image*]:

  ```
  In [7]: print img.im
  None

  In [8]: img.load()
  Out[8]: <PixelAccess at 0x7fe03ab6a210>

  In [9]: print img.im
  <ImagingCore object at 0x7fe03ab6a1d0>
  ```
- Let's now take a look in `load()`:
  I don't generally have the knowledge to know the internals here but I did observe something iffy: many **FIXME** comments before the assignment of `im`, specifically:

  ```
  # -- Omitting rest --         

  # FIXME: on Unix, use PROT_READ etc
  self.map = mmap.mmap(file.fileno(), size)
  self.im = Image.core.map_buffer(
                      self.map, self.size, d, e, o, a
                      )

  # -- Omitting rest --

  if hasattr(self, "tile_post_rotate"):
      # FIXME: This is a hack to handle rotated PCD's
      self.im = self.im.rotate(self.tile_post_rotate)
      self.size = self.im.size
  ```

  This might be an indication that there might be some issues needing attention here. ***I can't be 100% certain though.***

---

Of course, this might be caused by ***your image*** for some reason. The `load()` method worked fine with an image I supplied (and `pytesseract` just gave me a different error :P). You're better off probably creating a new [issue](https://github.com/python-pillow/Pillow/issues) for this. If any `PIL` experts happen to see this, enlighten us if you can.

Comment: Thanks for your interest and suggestions. I don't know enough about PIL to debug (if bug it is) the module so I will try and find other ways to do what I want.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, does `Image.open('foo.png').load()` return `None`?

Answer (score 0):

`im.load()` worked for me on running program in administrator mode and also add this line if you don't have tesseract executable in your PATH

```
pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:/Program Files (x86)/Tesseract-OCR/tesseract.exe'
```

If you have already read an image(not using im.load() but with imread()) or frame from video and did some image processing stuff(may be not) on that variable(image) then you need to give the following command
pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.fromarray(image))

Answer (score -1):

As @J_Mascis said,using objects worked here too-

```
    import pytesseract
    from PIL import Image
    img = Image.open('im.jpg')
    img.load()

    print(pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng'))#'eng' for english
```

Comment: So why did you post a duplicate answer?